# how to create a table in vaadin 10 and get data from mysql database

Tags: java, junit, akka

I am doing a project using vaadin and I am new to it. I want to create a table with 2 or 3 columns in a vertical layout and get values to it through my Myqsl database. Can anyone please help with this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample example: https://vaadin.com/blog/building-a-web-ui-for-mysql-databases-in-plain-java-

Good to refer vaadin documentation: http://demo.vaadin.com/

Sample Example:

```
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

@Route("")
public class VaadinUI extends VerticalLayout {

    private final CustomerService service;
    private Customer customer;

    private Grid<Customer> grid = new Grid<>(Customer.class);
    private TextField firstName = new TextField("First name");
    private TextField lastName = new TextField("Last name");
    private Button save = new Button("Save", e -> saveCustomer());

    public VaadinUI(CustomerService service) {
        this.service = service;

        grid.setColumns("firstName", "lastName");
        grid.addSelectionListener(e -> updateForm());

        add(grid, firstName, lastName, save);
        setMargin(true);
        setSpacing(true);
        updateGrid();
    }

    private void updateGrid() {
        grid.setItems(service.findAll());
        setFormVisible(false);
    }

    private void updateForm() {
        if (grid.asSingleSelect().isEmpty()) {
            setFormVisible(false);
        } else {
            customer = grid.asSingleSelect().getValue();
            Binder<Customer> binder = new Binder<>(Customer.class);
            binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
            binder.setBean(customer);
            setFormVisible(true);
        }
    }

    private void setFormVisible(boolean visible) {
        firstName.setVisible(visible);
        lastName.setVisible(visible);
        save.setVisible(visible);
    }

    private void saveCustomer() {
        service.update(customer);
        updateGrid();
    }

}
```

Complete example for Vaadin 10 implementation with WebUI and MySQL:

https://github.com/alejandro-du/mysql-jdbc-vaadin/tree/vaadin10

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response I'll check with the documentation,

Comment: @Nuiok1996 please checkout the above GitHub code and let me know in case any help needed. Please upvote and mark the answer as useful if the answered information helped you.